# Php's create_sid() any one used it?

Tags: php, function, session, manual

Was wondering how I can use this PHP function,   [PHP manual](http://php.net/manual/en/sessionhandler.create-sid.php)

`public string SessionHandler::create_sid ( void )`

it is clear that it takes none as argument and returns session id, how I can write this( in my custom session handler class)

```
    public function create_sid()
    {
        // return $id; <--- like this or nothing just need to call this when need to regenerate session id.
    }
```

PHP manual doesn't say anything clearly on this.

Comment: Depends really how your custom session handler class looks like.

Comment: @CharlotteDunois instead of calling session_regenerate_id(), can I call this function from my custom session handler class ? Link to my class http://codereview.stackexchange.com/questions/100448/simple-php-session-handler-class-using-mysql-for-session-data-storage

Comment: Well, actually I've never used that function and it seems to be new. I always used my own generate function to generate a random string. But if you have PHP 5.5.1+, you could use it. I tried to use it on 3v4l.org but only got `Fatal error: Undefined method` back.

Comment: @CharlotteDunois its not properly documented, anyways I was too using my own regenarte function , just thougt of giving it a try

Comment: I wonder what documentation you are expecting, it's a function with no arguments that returns a string, you can always [look at the source](https://github.com/php/php-src/blob/master/ext/session/session.c#L298-L441) - it's just a random string generator. If your session handler extends that class - just don't override the function, or do and call parent. I'm not sure what the actual question is, given how basic/fundamental these development tasks are...

Comment: @AD7six my question was if I write this function what should I return , eg return $sumting or nothing ?

Comment: _why_ would you override that function if you have no idea what to put in it? I suggest editing your question to make it obvious what your actual question is, or at the very least showing some of your code that would clarify in what way answering this question would help you.

Comment: I am not gonna overwrite, I was just curious to know if instead of calling session_regenarate_id(),  I can call create_sid() !  And I guess I am wrong its an callback when session_id is regenerated (not sure)